# How to use out attributes in an F# Interface?

Tags: f#

I would like to define one of my parameters to be a C# out parameter in one of my interfaces.  I realize that F# supports `byref` but how can I apply the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.OutAttribute` to one of my interface parameters?

C# Interface I am trying to replicate

```
public interface IStatisticalTests
{
    void JohansenWrapper(
        double[,] dat,
        double alpha,
        bool doAdfPreTests,
        out double cointStatus,
        out JohansenModelParameters[] johansenModelParameters);
}
```

Comment: Why would you need an interop attribute for this?  C# and F# are both managed code.

Comment: @Robert I don't believe F# has a built in `out` keyword.  Therefore the attribute must be used to emit the proper IL when compiling.

Comment: Yeah, but the attribute is associated with COM interop, not managed "interop."  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute.aspx  Ah, never mind.  It says there that it can be used for platform invoke also, and that it is equivalent to the `out` keyword in c#

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

[<Interface>]
type IPrimitiveParser =
    //
    abstract TryParseInt32 : str:string * [<Out>] value:byref<int> -> bool

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let parser =
        { new IPrimitiveParser with
            member __.TryParseInt32 (str, value) =
                let success, v = System.Int32.TryParse str
                if success then value <- v
                success
        }

    match parser.TryParseInt32 "123" with
    | true, value ->
        printfn "The parsed value is %i." value
    | false, _ ->
        printfn "The string could not be parsed."

    0   // Success
```

Here's your interface, translated:

```
[<Interface>]
type IStatisticalTests =
    //
    abstract JohansenWrapper :
        dat:float[,] *
        alpha:float *
        doAdfPreTests:bool *
        [<Out>] cointStatus:byref<float> *
        [<Out>] johansenModelParameters:byref<JohansenModelParameters[]>
            -> unit
```